# Android emulator doesn't load my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, logcat, genymotion

My Android emulator didn't load my app at all, it said it couldn't install .apk

Since changing emulators from the standard ones to Genymotion emulators my errors are different, here are my console & logcat.

```
    [2014-03-28 21:06:53 - LiverpoolPolls] ------------------------------
    [2014-03-28 21:06:53 - LiverpoolPolls] Android Launch!
    [2014-03-28 21:06:53 - LiverpoolPolls] adb is running normally.
    [2014-03-28 21:06:53 - LiverpoolPolls] Performing com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu activity launch
    [2014-03-28 21:06:53 - LiverpoolPolls] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
    [2014-03-28 21:06:57 - LiverpoolPolls] Uploading LiverpoolPolls.apk onto device '192.168.56.101:5555'
    [2014-03-28 21:06:58 - LiverpoolPolls] Installing LiverpoolPolls.apk...
    [2014-03-28 21:07:00 - LiverpoolPolls] Success!
    [2014-03-28 21:07:00 - LiverpoolPolls] Starting activity com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu on device 192.168.56.101:5555
    [2014-03-28 21:07:01 - LiverpoolPolls] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.liverpoolpolls/.Loadhomemenu }

And Logcat:

03-28 21:06:59.861: E/Trace(1084): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-28 21:07:00.153: D/dalvikvm(1084): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 102K, 2% free 8113K/8263K, paused 61ms, total 61ms
03-28 21:07:00.177: D/dalvikvm(1084): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 8466K/8647K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
03-28 21:07:00.185: E/FragmentManager(1084): No view found for id 0x7f050046 (com.example.liverpoolpolls:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
03-28 21:07:00.185: E/FragmentManager(1084): Activity state:
03-28 21:07:00.185: D/FragmentManager(1084):   Local FragmentActivity 53576384 State:
03-28 21:07:00.185: D/FragmentManager(1084):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):     mLoadersStarted=false
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):   Active Fragments in 53576be8:
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mFragmentId=#7f050046 mContainerId=#7f050046 mTag=null
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{53576be8 in Loadhomemenu{53576384}}
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):       mActivity=com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu@53576384
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):   Added Fragments:
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
03-28 21:07:00.189: D/FragmentManager(1084):   FragmentManager misc state:
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):     mActivity=com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu@53576384
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@53577084
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):   View Hierarchy:
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{535793c8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):       android.widget.LinearLayout{53579b2c V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{5357a104 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020319 android:id/action_bar_container}
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{5357a448 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102031a android:id/action_bar}
03-28 21:07:00.193: D/FragmentManager(1084):             android.widget.LinearLayout{5358197c G....... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):               android.widget.ImageView{53581f78 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102023b android:id/up}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):               android.widget.LinearLayout{535820ec V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):                 android.widget.TextView{5358231c V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020242 android:id/action_bar_title}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):                 android.widget.TextView{535829dc G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020243 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):             com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{53580154 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):               android.widget.ImageView{53580c40 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102023b android:id/up}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):               android.widget.ImageView{53580dc4 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{53582ce8 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102031b android:id/action_context_bar}
03-28 21:07:00.197: D/FragmentManager(1084):         android.widget.FrameLayout{53583018 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/FragmentManager(1084):           android.widget.RelativeLayout{535843d0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/FragmentManager(1084):             android.widget.ImageView{53584644 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003c app:id/imageView1}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/FragmentManager(1084):             android.widget.ImageButton{53562d80 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003d app:id/imageButton1}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/FragmentManager(1084):             android.widget.ImageButton{53562e70 VFED..C. ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05003e app:id/imageButton2}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/FragmentManager(1084):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{53583210 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102031c android:id/split_action_bar}
03-28 21:07:00.205: D/AndroidRuntime(1084): Shutting down VM
03-28 21:07:00.205: W/dalvikvm(1084): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6309288)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.liverpoolpolls/com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050046 (com.example.liverpoolpolls:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050046 (com.example.liverpoolpolls:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
03-28 21:07:00.205: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.liverpoolpolls"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadhomemenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Navigatefromhomepage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigatefromhomepage" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadingblogs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loadingblogs" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadingstatistics"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loadingstatistics" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadingpolls"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loadingpolls" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.liverpoolpolls.Loadingcontactus"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_loadingcontactus" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show your activity with manifest.

Comment: There is my manifest, thanks.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: The R.Java or the ones for the Activitys?

Comment: Whats the element with id 0x7f050046 inside your R.java?

Comment: Could you tell me how I'd go about finding that out for you? I don't usually touch the manifest so it means very little to me. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

this is the exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050046 (com.example.liverpoolpolls:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{53576600 #0 id=0x7f050046}
```

"**No view found for id**", generally caused by wrong layout specification in `inflate()` method or `setContentView()` of the activity